# typescript Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote a type for my click handle functions which return a value with the same type of it's parameter, the code is:

```js
type OnClickHandle =<T extends unknown = undefined>(p: T extends infer U ? U : T)=>
        T extends infer U ? 
        U extends number ? number:
        U extends string ? string :
        U extends undefined ?
        void :
        void :
        void
```

and then I defined my function like this:

```js
const handleReceive:OnClickHandle = (p:number) => p;
//ERROR:Type '(p: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'OnClickHandle'.
  Types of parameters 'p' and 'p' are incompatible.
    Type 'T extends infer U ? U : T' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322）
        
handleReceive(0);
```

I was frustrated with this message`'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'`,how can I make it works well?
any idea is appreciated !

Comment: my typescript version :3.7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: I suggest you use the following

```
type OnClickHandle<T> = (p: T) => T;
const handleReceive: OnClickHandle<number> = (p: number) => p;
```

Simple and works.

Issues with your code:

**You are trying to assign lambda with concrete type to generic function**

There are 2 kinds of generics in TS:

- Generic Types
- Generic functions

You cannot assign a labmda with a concrete type to generic function

```
type OnClickHandleGenericFunction = <T>(p: T) => T;
const handleReceiveGenFun1: OnClickHandleGenericFunction = (p: number) => p; //ERROR: number not assignable to T
```

It is highly unlikely that you want write a handler that handles any type f event in the same way, in such case you can assign a generic function to generic function type.

```
const handleReceiveGenFun: OnClickHandleGenericFunction = <T extends any>(p: T) => p;
```

**Use of unknown**

The error you receive says you cannot assign p to unknown.
That is not a surprise. See [unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)

**Convoluted type inferrence**

You introduced inferred type U for no reason.

```
T extends infer U ?
    U extends number ? number : void
```

Could be replaced with

```
T extends number ? number : void
```

Comment: thx a lot, are there more articles about  Generic Types and Generic functions?newer to ts

Answer (score 0):

```
type Test<T> = (arg: T) => T;
```

this is a normal function type, in which the type will be inferred from declaration

you can use it like this

```
const test:Test<number> = (p:number) => p;
```

And then there's your way

```
type Test = <T>(arg: T) => T;
```

this is a generic function type, in which the type will be inferred from parameters
you can use it like this

```
const test:Test = (p) => p;
test(3) // type is inferred here
```

so if we are not changing your type declaration, you implementation should look like this

```
const handleReceive:OnClickHandle = (p) => p; // do not declare type here, it is supposed to be generic
handleReceive(3);
```